# Create OneToOne instance on model creation

Tags: django, django-models

I'm building my first django app. I have a user, and the user has a list of favourites. A user has exactly one list of favourites, and that list belongs exclusively to that user.

```
class User(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=200)

class FavouriteList(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User)
    favourites = models.ManyToManyField(Favourite, blank=True)
```

When a new user is created, I want to ensure that the user has a `FavouriteList`. I've looked around in the Django documentation and haven't had much luck.

Does anyone know how I can ensure that a model has a child object (e.g. `FavouriteList`) when it is created?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Can Django automatically create a related one-to-one model?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1652550/can-django-automatically-create-a-related-one-to-one-model)

Answer (score 46, accepted):

The most common way to accomplish this is to use the Django signals system.  You can attach a signal handler (just a function somewhere) to the post_save signal for the User model, and create your favorites list inside of that callback.

```
from django.db.models.signals import post_save
from django.dispatch import receiver
from django.contrib.auth.models import User

@receiver(post_save, sender=User)
def create_favorites(sender, instance, created, **kwargs):
    if created:
        Favorites.objects.create(user=instance)
```

The above was adapted from the [Django signals docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/topics/signals/#connecting-to-signals-sent-by-specific-senders). Be sure to read the signals docs entirely because there are a few issues that can snag you such as where your signal handler code should live and how to avoid duplicate handlers.

Comment: updated the docs from 1.3 to 1.11. the `dev` docs would never be out of date, but maybe that would have been the better edit

Answer (score 8):

An excellent [django-annoying](https://github.com/skorokithakis/django-annoying) plugin solves this for you with `AutoOneToOneField`.  I'm using it for user profiles in all django projects I work on.

Comment: This is pretty cool...I seem to be jumping through this hoop more and more lately. Thanks for the tip.

Answer (score 5):

One way would be to register a [post_save](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/signals/#post-save) signal with next handler:

```
def user_save(sender, instance, created, **kwargs):
  if created:
     FavouriteList.objects.get_or_create(user=instance)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can override save method of User model.

```
def save(self, force_insert=False, force_update=False, using=None, update_fields=None):
    is_new = self.pk is None  # check if object is new to be saved
    super().save(force_insert, force_update, using, update_fields)
    FavouriteList.objects.create(user=self) if is_new else None
```

Comment: It might be valuable to know that `Model.save` isn't always called, [as when creating models through fixtures](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34365162/2989289), for example