# how to use the bulk_create() for many objects to do the save() operation

Tags: python, django, django-models, transactions

I have a lot of objects to save to the database, the code as below:

```
def addSthGroups(groups):
    for group in groups:  # each group is an object
        group.addSth()
        group.save()
```

and right now, it takes much time to save all of the object one by one. So my Question is: Is there a more efficient method to collect all of objects to just call the save() once, it may speed up the processing time, as I know, bulk_create sounds good to handle this scenario, can anyone give an example for this code? or any other good suggestion?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You can just do `Group.objects.bulk_create(groups)`, assuming that `Group` is the model name.

`bulk_create` won't call `save()`. Quoting from django [doc](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/models/querysets/#bulk-create):

> The model's `save()` method will not be called, and the `pre_save` and
>   `post_save` signals will not be sent.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, and where is the save(). Is it integrated to the bulk_create()?

Comment: So right now I can't use the bulk_create to collect all of objects to just call the save() once? do you have any other suggestion? Thanks.

Comment: Why do you want to call `save()`? You don't need to call `save()`, `bulk_create` will create everything in one shot.

Comment: I am not sure, new to django. I call addSth() for each object, and then I should save the new object to the database, the fixed code as below:   `def addSthGroups(groups):`
 `save_list = []`
 `for group in groups:`
  `group.addSth()`
  `save_list.append(group)`
 `adgroup.objects.bulk_create(save_list)`

Comment: I don't have your environment so there's no way I can try it out for you. You should try it yourself and post problems on stackoverflow if you have any, people are more than happy to help you.