# Django: OneToOneField relation on UUID with auto creation

Tags: django, python-3.x

I am aware of similar questions such as [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1652550/can-django-automatically-create-a-related-one-to-one-model) or [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5608001/create-onetoone-instance-on-model-creation) but I could not get to work none of the answers.

I have two models in **one models.py file**:

```
class Vehicle(models.Model):
    token = models.UUIDField(primary_key=True, default=uuid.uuid4, editable=False)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50)

class Model(models.Model)
    token = models.OneToOneField(Users, on_delete=models.CASCADE, primary_key=True)
    color = models.CharField(max_length=10, blank=True)
```

I want to upon adding a new Vehicle in django admin panel, a new record of Model also gets created and automatically bind the two on the same token which is in newly created Vehicle.

I know that I should set the `default` value of `OneToOneField` in Model class but I do not know how to get the `token` of newly created Vehicle.

Comment: this will help https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/signals/#post-save

Comment: using signals and the link you provided solved the problem. thanks.