# Matching query does not exist (Django)

Tags: django

I created a forum website.
When pressing on a user profile i get and error in console that **library.models.SiteUser.DoesNotExist: SiteUser matching query does not exist.**

And in the browser it also displays:
**DoesNotExist at /profile/1/**

**SiteUser matching query does not exist.**

Browser highlights this line
**userprof = SiteUser.objects.get(id=pk)**

This is my views.py:

```
def userProfile(request, pk):
    user = User.objects.get(id=pk)
    **userprof = SiteUser.objects.get(id=pk)**
    posts = user.post_set.all()
    post_comments = user.comment_set.all()
    interests = Interest.objects.all()
    context = {
        'user': user,
        'userprof': userprof,
        'posts': posts,
        'post_comments': post_comments,
        'interests': interests
    }
    return render(request, 'library/profile.html', context)
```

models.py:

```
class SiteUser(models.Model):
    page_user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    about = HTMLField()
    profile_pic = models.ImageField('profile_pic', upload_to='covers', null=True)
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

User and SiteUser primary keys will not be same. You can easily get SiteUser from the following query:

```
userprof = user.siteuser  # efficient solution
```

Or

```
userprof = SiteUser.objects.get(page_user_id=pk)  # alternative solution but should not be used in this code sample
```

Because of their OneToOne relation. For more information, please check the [documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/topics/db/examples/one_to_one/).

Comment: Unfortunately didn't fix my problem now in browser it says RelatedObjectDoesNotExist at /profile/1/ User has no siteuser. When I changed the line to userprof = user.siteuser

Comment: Then there is no SiteUser created for the User object. Make sure to create one or automatically create one. Django signals is a good solution here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5608001/create-onetoone-instance-on-model-creation

Comment: And when i change the line to userprof = SiteUser.objects.get(user_id=pk) browser says: FieldError at /profile/1/
Cannot resolve keyword 'user_id' into field. Choices are: about, id, page_user, page_user_id, profile_pic

Comment: sorry it should be page_user_id, but either way the problem will still remain as explained in last comment

Answer (score 0):

If you have relations, then always use them if possible. Instead of getting `SiteUser` having a `User` `pk` (it does not have to be always the same), get it using the relation between them:

```
# bad and risky
user = User.objects.get(id=pk)
userprof = SiteUser.objects.get(id=pk)

# good and always working if object exists
user = User.objects.get(id=pk)
userprof = user.siteuser
```

Good practice is to name `related_name` argument for such usage:

```
class SiteUser(models.Model):
    page_user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='foobar')
```

Then you can call it like:

```
user = User.objects.get(id=pk)
userprof = user.foobar
```

Comment: Unfortunately didn't fix my problem now in browser it says RelatedObjectDoesNotExist at /profile/1/
User has no siteuser. When i changed the line to userprof = user.siteuser

Comment: @nasosas does he have related siteuser? Check in database. If there is no relation, then it will never work :) You need to create such object manually then.