# How create new object automatically after creating other object in django?

Tags: django, django-models

For example, I have two classes.

```
class Book(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField (...)    
    author = models.CharField (...)
    price = models.Integer(...)

class Order(models.Model)
    order_datetime = models.DateTimeField()
    order_book = models.ForeignKey(Book,....)
```

New Order object should be created **automatically** after each addition of a new Book object in the database. And order_book fielt should be autocomplited with correspending book object.

How can I make it?

Thanx for the help!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Can Django automatically create a related one-to-one model?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1652550/can-django-automatically-create-a-related-one-to-one-model)

Answer (score 3):

You can override the save method of Book:

```
class Book(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField (...)    
    author = models.CharField (...)
    price = models.Integer(...)

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        is_new = True if not self.id else False
        super(Book, self).save(*args, **kwargs)
        if is_new:
            order = Order(order_book=self)
            order.save()
```

You can also add auto_now_add=True to order_datetime if it's supposed to be filled with insertion time:

```
order_datetime = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
```

Comment: Thanx a lot, nima!  I will try to use it.

Comment: this line I can't understand  ``` is_new = True if not self.id else False

Comment: You need to to decide whether the Book is saved for the first time, before calling super because it will have an id after that anyways.

Comment: when I try to do this I get an error in order_book, Im guessing its because when creating an order the book is not a parameter