# Can I create a related Django field between two models with a shared foreign key value?

Tags: django, django-models, django-model-field

I have two models:

```
class Foo(Model):

     special_id = IntegerField(primary_key=True)

class FooDetail(Model):

     special_id = IntegerField(primary_key=True)
```

`special_id` comes from an outside source -- it's a foreign key into another database.  Yes, `Foo` and `FooDetail` should be combined into a single model -- but assuming I can't -- can I create a related field between the two models such that I can use it in queries (like in `values` or `select_related`)?

I could add a `ForeignKey('FooDetail')` in `Foo`, but I'd be essentially storing the `special_id` twice.

Comment: Related -- or almost the same -- question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34501313/django-model-foreign-key-as-primary-key

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use the ORM's features for related models, you should create a relationship ([one-to-one](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/topics/db/examples/one_to_one/) in this case) between the two models. In one of the models you can (and should) then omit the `special_id` reference.

---

You can use the foreign key as a primary key in `FooDetail`, and if you keep `special_id` as a primary key in `Foo`, you'll be saving exactly the same type and amount of columns and data as in your example (namely one column in each that contains the relevant `special_id`).

What you get though is the benefit of a relationship and enforced integrity.

The only difference is that when you introduce a new `special_id`, you have to create `Foo` first to be able to point to it in `FooDetail` – hardly a big price to pay.

---

If you get a warning on setting the reference field to `Foo` to be the primary key then it might be that you defined it as a `ForeignKey`. You should define the field as a [`OneToOneField`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/models/fields/#onetoonefield) since you're dealing with a one-to-one relationship as noted above. The field is still technically a foreign key (= reference to the primary key of a row in another table) which is why I used this term; but it has a unique constraint that allows it to be used as a primary key.

Comment: yeah, that's what I was afraid of.  Not a big deal, but it adds an unneeded primary key to the FooDetail.

Comment: Django gives a big warning about using the foreign key as the primary key, so i've gone ahead and left special_id AND the foreign key... which both have the same value.